# fsf and bfs showing different output

Tags: tape

I am using *mt* utility to write a data on LTO 5,Data stored at sequentially on the tape and file will be identified by File 1, 2 ,3
I want to read the file 3 for that I am using fsf and bsf but I am confused.

If I run *mt -f /dev/nst0 fsf 1* then its goes to next file but how can I traverse directly to file no 3 , Its confusing me.

Comment: If your tape drive supports it, you can do `mt -f /dev/nst0 asf 3`. "a" stands for "absolute positioning".

Answer (score 0):

Please see the image below:[image: mt command fsf and fsfm]

As you can see here, you can go to the beginning of the file no 3 with:

```
$ mt -f /dev/st0 fsf 2
```

NOTE that you need to rewind tape before this command.

Also, as Mark has already suggested, you can use:

```
$ mt -f /dev/st0 asf 2
```

`asf` is equivalent to `rewind + fsf`.

Comment: The image  adds very little to the answer.